# Static files served from localhost but not from remote server (ask credentials)

Tags: django, windows, iis, static-libraries

I have set a virtual directory where I have my static files being served on IIS.

the static folder points to a shared drive.

when I use the website from localhost the "download" button downloads the file right away, but when I do it from a remote website it asks me for credentials (which are also always invalid)
I think it might be a thing about permissions, but I don't get what could be wrong.

Authentication Type is set to

```
Windows Authentication
Anonymous Authentication
```

to both the website and the static folder in IIS

I played around with different combinations of these Auth. types but I couldn't get it to work

[image]

there is also this setup on the static folder:
[image]

Comment: Disable windows authentication so that no credentials are required.